# Python Comparing and deleting files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list created from file names from folder like this:

filename_1, filename_2, filename_3....

Let's say that first part before "_" is file name and number after is version. I need to compare all files with same file name, keep file with highest and delete other from folder.

So far I've managed to load files from folder, split to `file_name` and `version` and create list with file names.

```
file_list = []    
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('folder_path'):

        for filename in files:
            file_version = filename.split('_')
            file_name = parts[0]
            version = int(parts[1])
            file_list.append(filename)
```

Comment: You're doing great, keep going

Comment: use a dictionary  with the filename as the key and the value being a list of versions. You can then look at each key and sort the list and delete the old ones. hint: dict().setdefault is often useful with this pattern.

Comment: I suggest to learn Git version control system to avoid the wheel reinvention :)

Comment: @pepr a full-fledged VCS may be an overkill depending on the task, so I wouldn't suggest it blindly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Yes and no. The question is vague in the sense what is the real motivation. Storing the file versions as named based on its content may be useful on its own. Also, Git is already installed on many systems. Moreover, it is easy to install, and it is useful for more things than just this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet achieving what you are looking for :

```
import os

version_matching = {}

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('test'):

    print("Entering " + path)

    for filename in files:
        parts = filename.split('_')

        file_name = parts[0]

        try:
            version = int(parts[1])
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            # In case some files don't follow the pattern
            print("Skipping " + path + '/' + filename)
            continue

        if file_name not in version_matching:

            # First time we see this file, save the informations

            version_matching[file_name] = {"version": version,
"path": path + '/' + filename}

        elif version_matching[file_name]["version"] > version:

            # We have already seen the file,
            # but the one we are handling has a lower version number,
            # we delete it

            print("Removing " + path + '/' + filename)
            os.remove(path + '/' + filename)

        else:

            # We have already seen the file,
            # but this version is more recent,
            # we delete the saved one

            print("Removing " + version_matching[file_name]["path"])
            os.remove(version_matching[file_name]["path"])

            # And we update the saved infos

            version_matching[file_name]["version"] = version
            version_matching[file_name]["path"] = path + '/' + filename
```

You may want to comment out the `os.remove` lines to make sure it does the proper thing.

I used a dictionary to store the informations of the file with the highest version number, and every time I find a file with the same name, I compare the version number and delete the older file.

Also note that the code won't harm files not following the specified pattern (`.*_[0-9]*`).

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Comment: @monk_13 glad I could help =)
Can you accept my answer if you no longer need help regarding this matter ?